# Sync data between two FileMaker12 instances through ODBC

Tags: odbc, filemaker

I'd like to know, if there's a way to sync data between two FileMaker 12 instances through an ODBC connector. To be honest, I found how to set-up a DNS, but the problem is that I'm not able to connect from server B to server A, since it says, that the type of data source is not supported

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Surely you're not talking about [Football Manager 2012](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=fm12) here, so please expand.

Comment: Nope, im not. Its just that its so trivial for me, since I use it everyday